# The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

Can any body give the suggestions.Why I am getting this error.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_*GL10000*_TRXDATE__56701F76". The conflict occurred in database "TWO", table "dbo.GL10000", column 'TRXDATE'.

This is my stored procedure :

```
SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand("taGLTransactionHeaderInsert", strcon);

  myCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  myCommand1.CommandText = "taGLTransactionHeaderInsert";

  myCommand1.Parameters.Add("@I_vBACHNUMB", SqlDbType.Char).Value = GLHdr.BACHNUMB;

  myCommand1.Parameters.Add("@I_vREFRENCE", SqlDbType.Char).Value = "ExcelImport";

  myCommand1.Parameters.Add("@I_vTRXDATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = GLHdr.TRXDATE;
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GL10000](

[PSTGSTUS] [smallint] NOT NULL,

[LASTUSER] [char](15) NOT NULL,

[LSTDTEDT] [datetime] NOT NULL,

[USWHPSTD] [char](15) NOT NULL,

[TRXTYPE] [smallint] NOT NULL

    /* More columns? not included in script that OP added */
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GL10000]  WITH CHECK ADD CHECK
  ((datepart(hour,[RVRSNGDT])=(0) AND datepart(minute,[RVRSNGDT])=(0)
  AND datepart(second,[RVRSNGDT])=(0) AND datepart(millisecond,[RVRSNGDT])=(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GL10000]  WITH CHECK ADD CHECK
  ((datepart(hour,[Tax_Date])=(0) AND datepart(minute,[Tax_Date])=(0)
  AND datepart(second,[Tax_Date])=(0) AND datepart(millisecond,[Tax_Date])=(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GL10000]  WITH CHECK ADD CHECK
  ((datepart(day,[TIME1])=(1) AND datepart(month,[TIME1])=(1)
  AND datepart(year,[TIME1])=(1900)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GL10000]  WITH CHECK ADD CHECK
  ((datepart(hour,[TRXDATE])=(0) AND datepart(minute,[TRXDATE])=(0)
  AND datepart(second,[TRXDATE])=(0) AND datepart(millisecond,[TRXDATE])=(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GL10000] ADD  CONSTRAINT
  [DF__GL10000__DEX_ROW__540C7B00]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [DEX_ROW_TS]
GO
```

Comment: Unique constraint? FK constraint? Can you post it?

Comment: Let me know how to find the which constraint is raising error.In error description i did not find any constraint.

Comment: Use SQL Mgmt Studio, select the table GL10000 and expand.  But the name is CK_GL10000_TRXDATE__56701F76

Comment: I saw that.How can i solve this issue by using that constraint.

Comment: Right click on the table and select "Script table as" then "CREATE to" then "New Query Editor Window".  Copy/paste the contents here.

Comment: Can you look at that content. i just edited.

Comment: Looks like the constraint on `TRXDATE` is validating the `datetime` has no time component and you are passing data that violates this. You might want to consider using the `DATE` datatype instead of `datetime` for this column.

Answer (score 2):

There is a CHECK constraint on the table, and the value you are passing to the stored procedure either doesn't match the check constraint, or isn't the value that's trying to make it as far as the TRXDATE column in the GL10000 table. Your easiest bet is to use SSMS to explore this table and find the CHECK constraint.

Comment: In GL10000 table i have this costraint :CK__GL10000__TRXDATE__56701F76. Can you explain how can i solve my issue

Comment: @KiranReddy - you need to view the definition of that constraint - it could contain practically any valid SQL expression - we don't know what's inside there.

Answer (score 2):

In the stored procedure 'taGLTransactionHeaderInsert', add the following line somwhere near the top, prior to the insert.

```
set @I_vTRXDATE = convert(varchar, @I_vTRXDATE, 101)
```

In SQL 2008, you can also use the DATE data type.

```
create proc taGLTransactionHeaderInsert
{
    @I_vTRXDATE DATE
}
```

And CAST as DATE

```
DECLARE @I_vTRXDATE2 DATE
SET @I_vTRXDATE2 = CAST(@I_vTRXDATE as DATE)
```

This will remove the time portion of whatever datetime value is being passed in.  However, if passing in date + time is incorrect, then the error is likely to be expected and you should correct the value being passed into the stored procedure running any business logic rules necessary to satisfy the requirements.

You could also truncate the value being passed in, i.e.

```
GLHdr.TRXDATE.Date;
```

Also note that in SQL 2008, the DATE data type was introduced.  You can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx).

Personally, I would remove the constraint.  TRXDATE sounds like it stands for "transaction date".  Generally, one would want to know the exact date and time that a transaction occurred.  For presentation purposes, if you only want the DATE to be displayed, then simply truncate the time but your data would be completely intact.

Comment: I worked with this same stored procedure with this value. (GLHdr.TRXDATE  value :"12-05-2007 12:15:15"). Today i am trying to execute using same value.Today only am getting errors. I am wondering why this happening.

Comment: Possibly something changed in code, can't say for sure, but I do know that the data provided will conflict with the supplied constraints.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since this question was arisen,
I got a similar error, so did this to find out what was exactly the rule in **CHECK**:
From SQL server management (my current version 2012), click on the table that is causing the error, then expand the **Constraints** folder,
right click on the problematic Constraints and select the "**Modify**", this will show the definition of constraint, 
you can easily find the **CHECK** part in the definition, for my case it was checking if my column is getting only 
character of 'C' or 'O' for my the column, while in the code, I was trying to insert a character of 'E'.

Constraint definition:

```
    CHECK  (([ColumnName]='C' OR [ColumnName]='O'))
```

My code:

```
         switch (item.Type)
           {
            case myType.Elective:
                entityName.ColumnName = "E";
                .
                .
                .
            }
```

Based on this CHECK part, you can modify your code to full fill the check condition, or if the check condition is not right, just modify that.